# Create solid blue boxes of uniform size around different sized text

Tags: html, text, html-lists

I have a list of links running the height of a page, and I want to put each one in a uniformly sized (regardless of text length) blue boxes.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It'll be easier to give a specific answer if you provide a snippet of your code, but yes it's possible. Give the boxes a css class with a set width.

```
.links {
   width: 150px;
   height: 40 px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hxexLeu6/

Comment: Check out the jsfiddle, specifying the width and height make all the boxes uniform, regardless of length.